# Custom physics body adding unwanted extra line

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have made a node with three custom physics bodies, the problem however is that there is for each physics body an extra line.

I it possible to remove these lines? The lines that I would like to remove are circled with red.

I have made the physics bodies with [this editor](http://adriancooney.ie/SKImport/Editor/).

With the paths I have created this code (swift & sprite kit):

```
//Wheel
    let wheel = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "wheel")
    let scaleWheel = frame.width / wheel.frame.width * 0.8
    wheel.name = "wheel"
    wheel.position = view.center

    //Scale constants
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame))
    let offsetX: CGFloat = sprite.frame.size.width * sprite.anchorPoint.x
    let offsetY: CGFloat = sprite.frame.size.height * sprite.anchorPoint.y

    //path
    let path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, -172 - offsetX, 143 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -151 - offsetX, 122 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -167 - offsetX, 100 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -178 - offsetX, 81 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -186 - offsetX, 60 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -191 - offsetX, 38 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -193 - offsetX, 16 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -193 - offsetX, -7 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -193 - offsetX, -25 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -188 - offsetX, -47 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -182 - offsetX, -69 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -173 - offsetX, -88 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -164 - offsetX, -105 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -151 - offsetX, -124 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -134 - offsetX, -143 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -150 - offsetX, -168 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -170 - offsetX, -147 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -190 - offsetX, -121 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -207 - offsetX, -89 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -218 - offsetX, -58 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -224 - offsetX, -23 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -224 - offsetX, 25 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -216 - offsetX, 62 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -208 - offsetX, 85 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -192 - offsetX, 116 - offsetY)

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

    //pathTwo
    let pathTwo: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()

    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathTwo, nil, -93 - offsetX, 170 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, -117 - offsetX, 193 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, -93 - offsetX, 205 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, -66 - offsetX, 215 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, -43 - offsetX, 221 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, -21 - offsetX, 224 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, -2 - offsetX, 226 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 22 - offsetX, 226 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 46 - offsetX, 221 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 63 - offsetX, 216 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 85 - offsetX, 209 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 111 - offsetX, 197 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 137 - offsetX, 179 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 160 - offsetX, 160 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 181 - offsetX, 135 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 200 - offsetX, 106 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 214 - offsetX, 74 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 223 - offsetX, 37 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 192 - offsetX, 37 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 186 - offsetX, 65 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 170 - offsetX, 99 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 139 - offsetX, 137 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 95 - offsetX, 169 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, 46 - offsetX, 191 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, -4 - offsetX, 195 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathTwo, nil, -61 - offsetX, 183 - offsetY)

    CGPathCloseSubpath(pathTwo)

    //pathThree
    let pathThree: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()

    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathThree, nil, 192,-38 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 223,-38 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 219,-61 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 209,-91 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 196,-116 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 176,-145 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 149,-172 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 111,-198 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 79,-213 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 46,-222 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 15,-227 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, -19,-226 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, -49,-222 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, -71,-216 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, -87,-209 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, -72,-183 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, -39,-194 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 5,-197 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 52,-189 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 99,-170 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 141,-136 - offsetY)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathThree, nil, 176,-87 - offsetY)

    CGPathCloseSubpath(pathThree)

    //Physics bodies
    let bodyOne = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)
    let bodyTwo = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: pathTwo)
    let bodyThree = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: pathThree)

    wheel.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [bodyOne, bodyTwo, bodyThree])
    wheel.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 5
    wheel.physicsBody?.pinned = true
    wheel.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    wheel.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    wheel.setScale(scaleWheel)
    addChild(wheel)
```

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2bmZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I did some extra research and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143074/ios-bodywithpolygonfrompath-body-is-the-same-as-the-path-but-collisions-are/21144259#21144259) post came up.

The solution:

> Use `bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:` or `bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath:` to be able to create concave collision shapes. These bodies will not be
>   dynamic and won't be able to move by themselves but they are the
>   perfect solution for arbitrary collision shapes with a static
>   playfield.